# Using HLL_COUNT.MERGE outside of SQL

Tags: algorithm, google-bigquery, hyperloglog

I can use the following query to general all the HLL sketches of the distinct counts:

```
SELECT category, count(distinct city), HLL_COUNT.INIT(city) FROM `table`
GROUP BY category
```

And I get something like this:

[image]

While I would normally use the `HLL_COUNT.merge(...)` function to get the total count, for example:

```
select 'all -- hll', HLL_COUNT.MERGE(x), null from (select category, count(distinct city), HLL_COUNT.INIT(city) x from `datadocs-163219.010ff92f6a62438aa47c10005fe98fc9.inv` group by category) _
```

[image]

For various reasons, I need to do the `MERGE` outside of SQL/BigQuery. Is there some sort of library/open source library where I could do something like the following:

```
>>> hll_set
>>> {'CHAQMBgCIAuCBz8QFBgPIBQyN8hxlqEBvMMBnLMBgWnD5gTB3AH+ROgD/YMEpM8Jr70C6Q2LwwfZlQ3QMNu8AYDSBKf7AbOSqgE=',  'CHAQDhgCIAuCBxwQBxgPIBQyFP3PBMBtibMR3sgC77oViasKwfMF', 'CHAQJxgCIAuCBzIQEBgPIBQyKshxlqEBvMMBzfECh6gJxJABoNwF/rEGwf0PgYYFvOoFmzjJPZwg2y3nbw==', 'CHAQBBgCIAuCBw4QAhgPIBQyBpSJAfapKA==', 'CHAQBRgCIAuCBxEQAxgPIBQyCbaJBfqsH57tBw==', 'CHAQGBgCIAuCBykQDRgPIBQyId6SAtNvwJ0XgO8Ct/EFlvUOskG1E87ZA7/OApwg2y3nbw==', 'CHAQZhgCIAuCB2MQIxgPIBQyW5SJAcqJAbzDAcvcAoIV2xSMFsTyA42IAYkl+Wvj/AHqdJxRlEGbywG/WNjoAqS9BP3CAuPrBNSFAfdDt+YEoeIBr+ICmIYF6CL/MaLNAqKdA8k9rxntBrPVrAE=', 'CHAQEBgCIAuCByQQChgPIBQyHN6SAqjtArAJ/esCj9wSg+8KiVKNygHrpgXIogU=', 'CHAQpgkYAiALggfZAhChARgPIBQyzwKPBMwRkAzxP+wPogyqC8qJAeBo8BHsSOypAbAJriL+MYYR/1jnKqIyzR3wJIkI/QXkecNH7WCzQZgMuDvxFLh+xkboA7QB12akDhu5E+4+3KgBjAZ4nxLBRMw0xRWvIPZYszt+v1gnz2a0BZoF4wzQggHqOewsJeAxgguGErUCjGG3KuhKgUyfCtItkjOMZZwCpi3phgHlA+wRknEhwiq1Os4slgmhELEWl1f1rgH+B6e4AdCtAdkE4R7fK/gihHSRFqipAbYY9BmqP5oBgqsBvhrvEKGRAcpj7XHEVaAUrY8BylLRDgWn1wGpT6IS6irPHewb/AbKHqgQjQPyAeU82zuSHpgQ04UBzwqkFIADiBD4X6ABjBihFsIy6wmovgHNKssPsQOvGcADrQOQevMQvxKMBtANizqbP7l21+kB0UDxY92rVYCBMcD5H8CiEA=='}

>>> hll_merge_method(hll_set)
>>> 193
```

Is it possible to do this in any way using a library outside of BQ with the hash generated from it?

Comment: That's a feature request you might already find in the issue tracker: the current hash is Google proprietary, but one day BigQuery could use an open one. Vote that request up

Comment: @FelipeHoffa -- I see, here's one that's related under Cloud Dataflow, which I upvoted -- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62153424

Comment: Hey @FelipeHoffa - would you be ok to promote your comment to an answer for posterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a feature request you might already find in the issue tracker: the current hash is Google proprietary, but one day BigQuery could use an open one. Vote that request up.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62153424

There might be news soon, and subscribing to the issue will keep you updated.

---

**2019 Update**: Find the open source version of BigQuery's HyperLogLog++ at:

- https://github.com/google/zetasketch

Comment: thanks fo this. Any idea when or if this will be implemented? It seems it's been on the shelf for two years now.

Comment: There might be news soon, and subscribing to the issue will keep you updated.

Comment: it looks like this has been completed. You can update your answer now to show how it's possible :) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62153424

Comment: Thanks for the ping! Would you accept the answer now?