# Possible to do a pivot outside of BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distinct, hyperloglog

Let's say I'm looking to build the following pivot table:

```
// count by age

 age     male     female
 1-25    18       23         
 26-100  19       10
```

To do this, I can do a basic aggregation like this:

```
SELECT age, gender, count(*) GROUP BY age, gender
```

And get results such as:

```
gender   age    count
male     1-25   18    
male     26-100 19    
male     1-25   23    
male     26-100 10
```

And then I can 'build the results' outside of BigQuery/SQL (such as in javascript or even pandas) to get the pivoted result.

However, I run into trouble when the values can't be simply "added up" or calculated in some straightforward fashion. For example:

```
// distinct users by country

country    male       female
us         192,293    64,000
jp         1,203,203  1,000,000
```

Is there a way to grab a value in BigQuery so that we can do this calculation outside of BigQuery? I've posted a preceding question to this here where it seems like you cannot use the `HLL_COUNT`, as that's not [available outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301007/using-hll-count-merge-outside-of-sql). [Or is there some other type of algorithm that can be applied to build some sort of unique sketch that can be merged outside SQL?].

Or is there another approach to building pivot results (outside of BigQuery) that I'm missing?

**Update**: The above examples are more to give an overview of the issue. The actual pivot queries would be like this: [Get the top patent countries, codes in a BQ public dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283851/get-the-top-patent-countries-codes-in-a-bq-public-dataset), on both the X and Y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand.  Why not do this *inside* BigQuery?

```
SELECT age,
       COUNTIF( gender = 'male' ) as males,
       COUNTIF( gender = 'female' ) as females
GROUP BY age;
```

Comment: it gets tricky, and the above is just a basic overview. In our pivot queries we would be doing this on both the X and Y axis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283851/get-the-top-patent-countries-codes-in-a-bq-public-dataset. In other words, we don't know the column headers to start...

Comment: @David542 . . . That is not the question that you asked here.  If you don't know the column headers, ask a *new* question.

Comment: new question added here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370630/doing-a-cross-pivot-in-google-bigquery?noredirect=1#comment99343780_56370630